# Which the Lowest Possible Solaris Version which supports TLS 1.2?

Tags: ssl, unix, solaris, versioning

I am currently using Solaris 5.8,with TLS 1.0, but now i would like to upgrade to TLS 1.2.
Since Solaris 5.8 doesnt support TLS 1.2.
What is the minimal upgrade i need to do( solaris Version) to use TLS 1.2
Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris 8 was released in the year 2000, and stopped receiving security patches in 2014.  If you need more security, you really need to upgrade to a current OS version, such as Solaris 11.4 (though a server old enough to run Solaris 8 probably can't support a current OS release).

In any case, TLS support depends on the application or library in use, far more than the OS - if it's your own application, this is probably OpenSSL, GnuTLS, or Mozilla NSS - if it's a web server, then Apache HTTPd, nginx, or whatever other server you use.